# A possible proof of the existence of a prime in the interval [n,2n].

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

Consider the theta function, $\theta(x)$=$\sum_{p\leq x} \log p$.

Lemma: $\theta(x)$ is strictly monotone increasing.

We thus have that $\theta(x)$<$\theta(2x)$. Note also that $\theta(2x)$=$\theta(x)$+$\sum_{p<q\leq2x} \log p$. So there is a q in between x and 2x. Assume there did not exist such a q. Then by the monotone condition, one has $\theta(x)$<$\theta(2x)$=$\theta(x)$+$\sum_{p<q\leq2x} \log p$. But by assumption, $\sum_{p<q\leq2x} \log p$=0. Thus we have that $\theta(x)$<$\theta(x)$. A contradiction. Thus we have a prime q, such that x<q$\leq$2x.

My only dilemma is the proof of the monotone condition. I can't seem to find it. But once I do, then this would imply Bertrand's postulate. I am sorry if I am not very good with these types of things. I just tried my best to find the most elementary proof of this conjecture.

So I would like to know if; 1) my proof is correct, 2) help with the proof of the lemma.

EDIT: The above lemma is false. Let me restate it:

Lemma: $\theta(x)$<$\theta(2x)$.
Now I need help with this lemma. :/

Comment: This makes no sense: $\theta(2x) = \theta(x) + \sum_{p<q\le 2x} \log p$. The correct formula is $\theta(2x) = \theta(x) + \sum_{x<p\le 2x} \log p$

Comment: @jjagmath Sorry typo. But it would still make sense, since p$\leq$ x<q$\leq$ 2x. People on math sites have no chill. I once commented on a blog saying, can I get a hello? And everyone pooped on me. Have fun guys. Its math.

Comment: I'm not been rude,  I just pointed your mistake.

Comment: No problem my homie.

Comment: You say that makes sense? How exactly did you got that equality?

Comment: All I did was split up $\theta(2x)$. This function very loosely counts primes. So what I wanted to do was go for a contradiction, so I wrote $\theta(2x)$ in terms of $\theta(x)$. To be honest, I can't explain things well. Sorry if you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

The correct formula is $$\theta(2x) = \theta(x) + \sum_{x<p\le 2x}\log p$$
Then $\theta(2n) > \theta(n)$ is equivalent to say that there is a prime in $(n,2n]$. However, $\theta(x)$ is NOT strictly increasing: $\theta(7)=\theta(8)=\theta(9)=\theta(10)$.

Comment: Yes I know. But I assumed for sufficiently large x, and 2x, since this question has been verified for arbitrarily large values. And I only proved it for the x and 2x case. Not the general a and b case, because then you would have problems like this. For instance, there exists composite numbers p, such that a^(p-1)=1(mod p), even though p does not divide a. (p=561). And we know this theorem, and the truth of it. So I only proved for x and 2x. Not generally for all a and b.

Comment: So I guess one just actually has to prove $\theta(x)$<$\theta(2x)$, not the monotone condition. I just realized that after watching some attack on titan. Alright.